# Execute a block of code but show all results in Julia/Juno

Tags: julia

I have Julia code edited in Juno, which contains a very simple code block with a calculation at each line. When I select it all and execute it, only the result for the last line is displayed:

[image]

I'd like to execute the block, but have the results for each line, like this (image obtained executing line by line):

[image]

Is it possible (via some shortcut or option)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do this yet, although it's something we'd like to see in future. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/one-more-minute/Julia-LT/issues/185) to track the feature.

One thing that might help is the `Shift-Enter` command, which is the same as `C-Enter` but skips to the next code block. If you repeatedly `Shift-Enter` from the beginning of that block of code you'll get all of the results very quickly, if not quite instantaneously.